# Date difference in days for Java7

Tags: java, date, java-7, jodatime, date-difference

I have date formats as: `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`

For ex.,

> Date 1 : Mon Sep 10 08:32:58 GMT 2018
>
> Date 2 : Tue Sep 11 03:56:10 GMT 2018

I need date difference as **1** in above case, but I am getting value as **0** if I use `joda` date time or manually converting date to milliseconds.

For reference : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/

Any leads will be helpful.
Example :

```
Date date1 = new Date("Mon Sep 10 08:32:58 GMT 2018");
Date date2 = new Date("Tue Sep 11 03:56:10 GMT 2018");
DateTime start = new DateTime(date1 );
DateTime end = new DateTime(date2);
int days = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
System.out.println("Date difference: " + days);
```

> Output: Date difference: 0

Comment: If you are using the code example you’ve referenced, you should note that for your input it gives 0 days as the time difference is less than a whole day and this rounds down.

Comment: Added example in question description

Comment: @Roy I need difference in days without considering time.

Comment: @Ole - Thanks for info! Following approach worked for me :
int days = Days.daysBetween(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate()).getDays();

Comment: I suggest migrating to a JSR310 library. A backport is available for java 6+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joda-Time counts only whole days, in other words, truncates the difference to a whole number. So with a little over 19 hours between your values it counts as 0 days. If you want to ignore the time part of the dates, convert to `LocalDate` first:

```
    int days = Days.daysBetween(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate()).getDays();
```

(Thanks for providing the concrete code yourself in a comment. Since you said it worked, I thought it deserved to be an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in previous comments, *Joda-Time* counts whole days and rounds down. Therefore you'll need to skip the time when comparing. Something like this will work, using *Java.time* comparing the dates:

```
Date date1 = new Date("Mon Sep 10 08:32:58 GMT 2018");
Date date2 = new Date("Tue Sep 11 03:56:10 GMT 2018");
LocalDate start = date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalDate end = date2.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
long between = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);

System.out.println("Date difference: " + between);
```

Comment: Are you using java.time rather than Joda-Time? A nice idea, but better to make it clear, please.

Comment: Yes, I was using java.time instead of yodatime when calculating the days between. Thanks for your constructive comment. The answer is updated with a clarification.